# Recreating Graph Using PGF Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to recreate the attached figure using PGF plots. Is there an easier way to do this? Is there a way to draw or create functions similar to this without having to necessarily know the equation of the function? I have tried using the hobby package and estimate points of the curve, but had no luck.

I know I could screen shot the pic, but it does not look as good. I would really like to learn how to do this more efficiently.  I am trying to use quadratic equations, but as you can see my figure is incomplete.  I hope it is possible.  I also would love to know how to draw the f(x) label node with the arrow.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{point/.style={circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[grid style={gray!50}, thick,
                    xlabel={\(x\)},
                    ylabel={\(y\)}, xmin=-4,xmax=6,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
            every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
            axis y line=center,
            axis x line=center,
            axis line style={Triangle-Triangle},
             ticklabel style={font=\small,fill=white},
             yticklabels=\empty,
              ytick=\empty
            ]
            \addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=-3:-2]{-2*(x+3)^2+2};
            \addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=0:2]{-(x-1)^2};

            \addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=-2:-1]{.5(x+1)^2-2};
            \draw[thick, dashed] (-3,0)--(-3,2);

            \addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=3:5]{-(x-5)^2+2};
            \draw[thick, dashed] (-3,0)--(-3,2);
            
            \draw[thick,dashed] (5,0)--(5,2);
            \draw[thick,dashed] (3,0)--(3,-3);
            \draw[thick,dashed] (-1,0)--(-1,-2);
            
             \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE: SOMEONE CLOSED THIS, NOT SURE WHY.  HERE IS A SOLUTION FROM A COLLEAGUE, STEFAN.

> 

you could include the original image as a node, draw a grid to see the coordinates, then choose as many coordinate values as possible and draw a smooth plot, then remove the image node:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 %\node[opacity=0.5] at (2.8,1.2) {\includegraphics{screenshot}};
 \draw[thin,dotted] (-8,-5) grid (12,3);
 \draw[->] (-8,0) -- (13,0);
 \draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,7);
 \draw plot [smooth,tension=0.7] coordinates {
   (-6.3,2.5) (-5.4,2) (-4.7,1) (-4,-0.5) (-3,-3) (-2,-3.6)
   (-1,-3) (0,-1.8) (1,-0.5) (2,0) (3,-0.5) (4,-1.8) (5,-3.2)
   (6.1,-4.1) (7,-3.2) (8,-0.6) (9,1) (10,2) (10.5,2.1)
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
'''
```

Comment: Where is figure?

Comment: Sorry, it is up there now!

Comment: Hm, this seem not to be LaTeX problem but math: how to define function showed on image.

Comment: Looks a little like the one [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318337239_MUBs_and_SIC-POVMs_of_a_spin-1_system_from_the_Majorana_approach/figures?lo=1)

Comment: You can answer your own question :) So instead of adding a possible solution to the question post, I suggest you post an answer with that code.

Comment: It was closed when I made the update, so I had to ask to have it reopened.

Answer (score 0):

With all your preamble and this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzset{point/.style={circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[grid style={gray!50}, thick,
                xlabel={\(x\)},
                ylabel={\(y\)}, xmin=-4,xmax=6,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
                every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
                axis y line=center,
                axis x line=center,
                axis line style={Triangle-Triangle},
                ticklabel style={font=\small,fill=white},
                yticklabels=\empty,
                ytick=\empty
                ]
                \addplot[cyan,thick,samples=1000,domain=-3:5]{cos(3*x*180/pi)-2*(sin(x*180/pi))^2};         
            \end{axis}
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Guess the equation of the function}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You have this output:

[image]

**But we need to know the equation of the function You need to plot**.

Comment: I can plot equations, that is not a problem. I don't have the equation of the function. I was wondering if it was possible using (hobby) or other package do get a general sketch of this curve without trying to guess what it is.  This is from an AP exam and equation is not included.

Comment: From my colleague Stefan, \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\node[opacity=0.5] at (2.8,1.2) {\includegraphics{screenshot}};
  \draw[thin,dotted] (-8,-5) grid (12,3);
  \draw[->] (-8,0) -- (13,0);
  \draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,7);
  \draw plot [smooth,tension=0.7] coordinates {
    (-6.3,2.5) (-5.4,2) (-4.7,1) (-4,-0.5) (-3,-3) (-2,-3.6)
    (-1,-3) (0,-1.8) (1,-0.5) (2,0) (3,-0.5) (4,-1.8) (5,-3.2)
    (6.1,-4.1) (7,-3.2) (8,-0.6) (9,1) (10,2) (10.5,2.1)
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}